# why does the bookmark did not get bigger

Tags: html, css, background, css-sprites

I'm trying to understand how [this site](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/nl-NL/what-is-the-internet/1) works because I want to use a similar solution on my own site.

The only thing I cannot figure out is how the red thing works, especially how the site knows which image to use. As background I see that sprites.png is used, but that one is filled with a lot of images.

What I would like to achieve is that the red thing is pulled out the whole time.

Comment: To avoid having this question closed as "Too Localized" consider finding the relevant snippets and including them in your post. Without the code, the question will not be useful to future StackOverflow visitors when the linked website restructures or goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you referenced uses "sprites" as background images.
Here is more information on [using sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Using sprites allows the site to load a single graphic containing [many sprites](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/css/images/sprites.png?v=15) and then position them by adjusting the `background-position` of elements to display specific areas of the "sprites" image.

The site is also using javascript to move the element up and down.
In order for the bookmark to stay pulled out, don't apply any javascript.

Comment: Thanks, The tip with the background-position was a good one.